# No matching function for call (STL QUEUE)

Tags: c++, struct, stl, queue

I am writing a program using an STL Priority Queue to simulate a line of customers at a bank, when coding my `processDeparture` function I get an error that states:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::priority_queue<Event>::push(int&)'
   eventListPQueue.push(customer.newDepartureEvent);
```

any help on fixing this error would be appreciated

Here is my code so far:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct Customer {
  int currentTime;
  int newDepartureEvent;
  int departureTime;
  int arrivalTime;
  int transactionTime;
  int customerID;
};

struct Event {
  int newDepartureEvent;
  int departureTime;
  int customerID;
  int transactionTime;
  int arrivalTime;
  int currentTime;

  // Used to compare events and determine highest priority
  bool operator<(const Event &right) const {
    return this->arrivalTime < right.arrivalTime;
  }
};

void simulate();
void processArrival(int &currentTime, Event &newEvent,
                    priority_queue<Event> &eventListPQueue,
                    queue<Customer> &bankQueue, bool tellerAvailable);
void processDeparture(Event &newEvent, priority_queue<Event> &eventListPQueue,
                      queue<Customer> &bankQueue, bool tellerAvailable);

int main() {
  simulate();

  return 0;
}

void simulate() {
  // Used to read in file
  ifstream File;

  // Declaring local variables
  int data;
  int arrivalEvent = 0;
  int transactionTime = 0;
  bool tellerAvailable = 0;

  // Creating an empty queue called bankQueue to represent a bank line
  // Creating an empty priority queue called eventListPQueue for an event list
  queue<Customer> bankQueue;
  priority_queue<Event> eventListPQueue;

  // Creating and adding arrival events to event list
  File.open("in1.txt");

  // Data file is not empty
  while (File) {
    // Getting next arriavl time and transaction time from file
    File >> arrivalEvent >> transactionTime;

    // cout << "test data: " << data << endl;
    cout << "test newArrivalEvent: " << arrivalEvent << endl;
    cout << "test transactionTime: " << transactionTime << endl;

    // a new arrival event containing a and t
    Event event;
    event.arrivalTime = arrivalEvent;
    event.transactionTime = transactionTime;
    eventListPQueue.push(event);
  }

  // Closing File
  File.close();

  // An Event loop
  int currentTime = 0;

  // Event loop
  while (!eventListPQueue.empty()) {  // Event list is not empty

    Event newEvent;

    newEvent = eventListPQueue.top();
    currentTime = newEvent.arrivalTime;  // Get current time

    if (newEvent.arrivalTime &&
        newEvent.departureTime == 0) {  // is an arrival event
      processArrival(currentTime, newEvent, eventListPQueue, bankQueue,
                     tellerAvailable);
    }

    else
      processDeparture(newEvent, eventListPQueue, bankQueue, tellerAvailable);
  }

  /*
          //Event list is not empty
          while (eventListPQueue.size() > 0 )
          {

                  Event newEvent;
                  newEvent = eventListPQueue.top();

                  //Get current time
                  currentTime = newEvent.arrivalTime;

                  // is an arrival event
                  if (newEvent.arrivalTime)
                          processArrival(newEvent, eventListPQueue, bankQueue);

                  else
                          processDeparture(newEvent, eventListPQueue,
     bankQueue);
  */
  //****************  pseudiocode to fill in
  //**************************************

  //// Processes an arrival event.
  // processArrival(arrivalEvent: Event, eventListPQueue : PriorityQueue,
  // bankQueue : Queue)
  //// Remove this event from the event list
  // eventListPQueue.remove()
  //
  // customer = customer referenced in arrivalEvent
  // if (bankQueue.isEmpty() && tellerAvailable) {

  //    departureTime = currentTime + transaction time in arrivalEvent
  //    newDepartureEvent = a new departure event with departureTime
  //    eventListPQueue.add(newDepartureEvent)
  //    tellerAvailable = false
  //}
  // else
  //    bankQueue.enqueue(customer)
  //
  //    // Processes a departure event .
  //    +processDeparture(departureEvent: Event, eventListPQueue: PriorityQueue,
  // bankQueue: Queue)

  //    // Remove this event from the event list
  //    eventListPQueue.remove()
  //
  //    if (!bankQueue.isEmpty()) {
  //
  //        // Customer at front of line begins transaction
  //        customer = bankQueue.peek()
  //        bankQueue.dequeue()
  //        departureTime = currentTime + transaction time in customer
  //        newDepartureEvent = a new departure event with departureTime
  //        eventListPQueue.add(newDepartureEvent)
  //    }
  //    else
  //        tellerAvailable = true
}

void processArrival(int &currentTime, Event &newEvent,
                    priority_queue<Event> &eventListPQueue,
                    queue<Customer> &bankQueue, bool tellerAvailable) {
  Event grab;
  Event event;
  Event eventCustomer;
  Customer customerIn_line;

  eventListPQueue.pop();  // Remove this event from the event list

  event.customerID++;  // customer = customer referenced in arrivalEvent
  if (bankQueue.empty() && tellerAvailable) {
    grab.departureTime =
        currentTime +
        newEvent.transactionTime;  //   departureTime = currentTime +
                                   // transaction time in arrivalEvent
    grab.newDepartureEvent =
        grab.departureTime;  // newDepartureEvent = a new departure event with
                             // departureTime
    eventListPQueue.push(grab);  // eventListPQueue.add(newDepartureEvent)
    tellerAvailable = false;     // tellerAvailable = false

  } else {
    customerIn_line.arrivalTime = event.arrivalTime;
    customerIn_line.transactionTime = event.transactionTime;
    bankQueue.push(customerIn_line);  //  bankQueue.enqueue(customer)
  }
}

void processDeparture(Event &newEvent, priority_queue<Event> &eventListPQueue,
                      queue<Customer> &bankQueue, bool tellerAvailable) {
  eventListPQueue.pop();

  Customer customer;

  if (!bankQueue.empty()) {
    customer = bankQueue.front();
    bankQueue.pop();
    customer.departureTime = customer.currentTime + customer.transactionTime;
    customer.newDepartureEvent = customer.departureTime;
    eventListPQueue.push(customer.newDepartureEvent);  // Where error occurs
  }

  else {
    tellerAvailable = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: `eventListPQueue` is for dealing with `Event`, so you cannot put `int` there as the message says. Push proper thing instead or remove the line.

Comment: Fixed it, Thank You!

I had another question, how would I go about implementing a priority_queue to take place? @MikeCAT